# how to run scripts with multiple python versions installed?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I have 2 versions of python installed on windows, 2.7.3 and 3.3. Some of my scripts are 2.x and some 3.x. Is there an easy way when executing these scripts from a command line to direct them to the appropriate interpreter?

Comment: Ubuntu installs aliases, `python2` and `python3`, however you don't mention what OS or installation packages you're using.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Note:** For Windows use the new Windows Python launcher (available with *Python 3.3* and downloadable [here](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher/downloads) for earlier releases) which recognizes Unix shell shebangs. You can read about it [here](http://blog.python.org/2011/07/python-launcher-for-windows_11.html).

Most Linux distributions will create `python2` and `python3` aliases for the installed *Python 2.x* and *Python 3.x* interpreter (if not you can just create the symbolic links yourself anywhere on your `$PATH`, the `env` command will take care of finding them), so you should just need to set the appropriate interpreter as the first line of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

This will direct the shell to use the appropriate interpreter, if you set the script files to be executable and just invoke them directly on the shell. E.g.:

```
$ chmod +x script.py
$ ./script.py
```

Comment: The poster didn't mention that Windows was the OS initially. :(

Comment: Yes, but its still possible to mess with PATH and aliases, i ll give it a shot

Comment: @U2ros See my improved answer with the reference to the new Windows Python launcher. That should be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this first: I am on OS X, but when I want to use Python 2.6 instead of Python 2.7 (its a numpy/scipy thing), I simply run python2.6 whatever.py to run whatever.py in Python 2.6. Try that first.

If that doesn't work, then you can use virtualenv - the virtual environment builder for Python.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

I am sure there are similar alternatives, too.

Comment: On ubuntu, im doing exactly that ;>

Answer (score 1):

Pedro Romano's answer is the most elegant way of doing this.

But if you don't want to download and install the Python launcher, create a batch file as described below. You can also create a shortcut, copy C:\Python27\python.exe to C:\Python27\python27.exe, etc.

I'm guessing C:\Python27 and C:\Python33 are already on your system path. If so, you can create a batch file called python2.7.bat in C:\Python27\ which contains:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe %1
```

and a similar file (e.g. python3.3.bat) in C:\Python33\

Now, you can run `python2.7 script.py` from anywhere in command prompt and it should work :)